# How to get the Add-On toolbar into Firefox 31?

Tags: firefox, toolbar

I recently upgraded to Firefox 31, from Firefox 28. Firefox 28 had the option for an Add-On toolbar, at the bottom of the browser window, where I placed various icons for fast access (such as Firebug, NoScript, LeechBlock, …; especially LeechBlock is quite wide and takes up lots of space on my non-widescreen), and to avoid making the location bar very short.

I cannot find this feature in Firefox 31, and I have to assume that it has been removed. Am I missing something? And if not, is there an Add-On which provides this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar, the excellent Classic Theme Restorer will also bring back the option for this, along with many other options.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/

Tap Alt to display the menu bar if hidden, then go to  View > Toolbars > Add-on bar and check that.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla has indeed removed the Add-On bar at the bottom of the screen. (see [What happened to the Add-On bar?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-to-the-add-on-bar)). The article links to [The Addon Bar (Restored)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-addon-bar/), an addon which can restore it.